# Stylesheet path issue

Tags: css, wordpress, stylesheet

I'm editing an app on my website but the style sheet is located in this path:

```
home/aib23/public_html/wp-content/themes/striking_r/assets/affiliate_app_css
```

what would the stylesheet look like for that path? This is what I thought it was:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" file://home/aib23/public_html/wp-content/themes/striking_r/assets/app_css" />
```

but it did not seem to work. Note that this stylesheet is placed within my wordpress theme folder.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance to those that contribute! :)

Comment: You should not be using absolute paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of path is local to the client system. So if I visit a page with this link it will look for your CSS file on my computer, at `/home/aib23/public_html/wp-content/themes/striking_r/assets/app_css`

Also, you need to use the href attribute in your link element in order for it to work.

I suggest you use a link relative to your web root - like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/wp-content/themes/striking_r/assets/affiliate_app_css/myfile.css" />
```

Replace myfile.css with the name of your stylesheet.

Comment: Thank you this worked, I had to leave out the home, aib23, and public html files in the path. Why is that?

Comment: Because this path is relative to the site's web root, which is different from the path on the computer on which it is hosted. Maybe it would be helpful for you to read the wikipedia page on URLs to help you wrap your head on it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator

Comment: Actually, you might find http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningtutorials/a/aa040502a.htm a little clearer.

Comment: @Ceili has answered with the best approach for this using wordpress

Comment: Ah okay, well tyvm for all the help guys. Much appreciated! :)

Comment: Hey guys, I'm back but its because I want to do something different pertaining to the same thing I did earlier with calling this stylesheet. Now I want to call it twice. Any advice from you guys would be appreciated! here is the thread where I posted my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23284021/call-2-stylesheets-for-different-pages-on-wordpress/23284061?noredirect=1#23284061

Answer (score 2):

The link to your stylesheet can be relative, but in this case you can harness WordPress's built in functions to make your life easier, like so:

```
<?php get_stylesheet_directory() ?>
```

[get_stylesheet_directory()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory) will automatically return the directory where WordPress is looking for the stylesheet. For example, if your stylesheet was named styles.css, you might use something like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php get_stylesheet_directory() ?>/styles.css">
```

You don't need to link the complete path to the file -- WordPress will take care of that for you.

Answer (score 0):

When linking to your stylesheet, you can either do it relatively or absolutely.  For instance, if you're linking to a stylesheet in the same directory as your HTML document, you can simply put

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
```

If, however, you want to refer to a main stylesheet throughout many HTML documents, you may want to stick with an absolute path.  In your case, something like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/wp-content/themes/striking_r/assets/app.css" />
```

Please note:  Your stylesheet file name should always end with `.css`.  Additionally, all `href` paths start after the `public_html` folder in your specific case.

Comment: Depending on the system and domain name setup, href paths could be relative to any directory on the server - which makes "all href paths start after the public_html folder" somewhat misleading

Comment: Right, I meant for this particular user's setup.