# Call 2 stylesheets for different pages on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, stylesheet

I currently have a form which I am displaying in the header of my page. This forms functionality is being rendered from a separate server which I do not have access to, though this is besides the point...

I am currently trying to display that same form on the side bar of another page, but I don't know how to call the forms style sheet twice within wordpress. Could someone please explain how I can do this? Much thanks to all who contribute! :)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to call the style sheet twice, as all styles is inherited throughout the html/php file  although you need to have the same html code for the form. The steps if i may suggest are:

1. Open your header.php
2. copy the html codes for the form
3. Open your sidebar.php
4. Paste the copied code in the spot that you want in sidebar.php

The form should be running fine by then.

Comment: I dont have access to the html, I only have access to the stylesheet. The form im calling is a php form where its html and functionality is from another server that I do not have access to. Right now I have a large version of the form in the header, Im going to change the stylesheet for it and call it in the a sidebar widget from its css class. The issue is that I will need to call the style sheet in two separate instances to make this work. Because if I use the same stylesheet it wont fit in the sidebar because it is very wide in the header. With css adjustments I can make it fit.

Answer (score 0):

Use `@import` to import css from external link. See sample code below:

```
@import url('add url of the stylesheet here');
```

For example:

If you want to add stylesheet of `http://yourdomain.com/css/custom.css`

You code will be:

```
@import url('http://yourdomain/css/custom.css');
```

You need to add `@import url();` in your stylesheet in above format to include stylesheet form external file or link.